# how to get the output of proc tabulate (SAS) in R

Tags: r

Is there any R function which could give me directly the same output of proc tabulate ??

```
var1<-c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4))
var2<-c(rep("C",4),rep("D",4))
var3<-c(rep("E",2),rep("F",4),rep("G",2))
dataset<-data.frame(var1,var2,var3)
```

```
proc tabulate data=dataset;
class var1 var2 var3;
table var1*var2 ,var3 all (n rowpctn);
run;
```

The output that I want is like this:

[image]

Comment: okay, I modified the post providing more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way with `R` -

1. Create a column of 1s - `n`
2. Expand the data to fill the missing combinations - `complete`
3. Reshape to 'wide' format - `pivot_wider`
4. Create the 'Total' column by getting the row wise sum - `rowSums`
5. Add the percentage by looping `across` the 'var3' columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
dataset %>%
    mutate(n = 1, var3 = str_c('var3_', var3)) %>% 
    complete(var1, var2, var3, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = var3, values_from = n, values_fn = sum) %>% 
    mutate(Total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>% 
    group_by(var1) %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with('var3'), 
     ~ case_when(. == 0 ~ '0(0%)', 
       TRUE ~ sprintf('%d(%d%%)', .,  100 * mean(. != 0))))) %>% 
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  var1  var2  var3_E var3_F var3_G Total
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A     C     2(50%) 2(50%) 0(0%)      4
2 A     D     0(0%)  0(0%)  0(0%)      0
3 B     C     0(0%)  0(0%)  0(0%)      0
4 B     D     0(0%)  2(50%) 2(50%)     4
```

#### Update

Based on the comments by @IceCreamToucan, there was a bug, which is corrected in the below code

```
dataset %>%
    mutate(n = 1, var3 = str_c('var3_', var3)) %>% 
    complete(var1, var2, var3, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = var3, values_from = n, values_fn = sum) %>% 
    mutate(Total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric))),  
    100 * across(starts_with('var3'),  ~ . != 0, 
      .names = "{.col}_perc")/rowSums(across(starts_with('var3'), ~ .!= 0)), 
     across(matches('var3_[A-Z]$'), ~ case_when(. == 0 ~ '0(0%)', 
     TRUE ~ sprintf('%d(%.f%%)', ., get(str_c(cur_column(), '_perc')))))) %>% 
    select(-ends_with('perc'))
```

Comment: I don't think the last step is calculating percentages correctly. Should be by row, not by column (SAS rowpctn is used).  It just so happens that in this example the row and column percents are the same so the results match. But that isn't always true. For example, start with `dataset %>% bind_rows(tibble(var1 = 'A', var2 = 'D', var3 = 'E'))` instead of `dataset` and the first row percents total 150%.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan can you check the updated code

Comment: It is correctly calculating percentages based on row now

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more generic version, where I define a function.

```
var1<-c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4))
var2<-c(rep("C",4),rep("D",4))
var3<-c(rep("E",2),rep("F",4),rep("G",2))
df<-data.frame(var1,var2,var3)

df_tabulate(df, id_cols = c(var1, var2), names_from = var3) 
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   var1  var2  var3_E   var3_F   var3_G   Total
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 A     C     2(50.0%) 2(50.0%) 0(0.0%)      4
#> 2 A     D     0(0%)    0(0%)    0(0%)        0
#> 3 B     C     0(0%)    0(0%)    0(0%)        0
#> 4 B     D     0(0.0%)  2(50.0%) 2(50.0%)     4
```

You can define the function using `janitor`

```r
library(janitor, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(rlang)
library(tidyr)

df_tabulate <- function(df, id_cols, names_from){
  id_cols <- enquo(id_cols)
  if (quo_is_call(id_cols, 'c'))
    id_cols <- call_args(id_cols)
  else
    id_cols <- ensym(id_cols)
  names_from_chr <- as_label(enquo(names_from))
  
  counts <- df %>% 
      mutate(g = eval(call2(paste, !!!id_cols, sep = ',')),
             col = paste0(names_from_chr, '_', {{ names_from }})) %>% 
      tabyl(g, col) %>% 
      adorn_totals('col') 
  
  percs <- adorn_percentages(counts) %>% 
    adorn_pct_formatting()
  
  rbind(counts, percs) %>% 
    group_by(g) %>% 
    summarise(across(-Total, ~ paste0(first(.), '(', last(.), ')')), 
              Total = as.numeric(first(Total))) %>% 
    separate(g, into = as.character(id_cols)) %>% 
    complete(!!!id_cols) %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with(names_from_chr), ~ coalesce(., '0(0%)')),
           across(Total, ~ coalesce(., 0)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is as a single pipeline with discrete simple steps.  Long, to be sure, but if you wanted many tables like this you could store it as a function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

dataset %>%
  mutate(across(var1:var2, as.factor)) %>%
  count(var1, var2, var3, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  unite(vars, var1, var2) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var3, values_from = n) %>%
  select(-`NA`) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  adorn_totals("col") %>%
  adorn_percentages(,,,,-c(vars, Total)) %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0,,,,-c(vars, Total)) %>%
  adorn_ns(position = "front",,,-c(vars, Total)) %>%
  separate(vars, into = c("var1", "var2"))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   var1  var2  E       F       G       Total
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 A     C     2 (50%) 2 (50%) 0  (0%)     4
#> 2 A     D     0   (-) 0   (-) 0   (-)     0
#> 3 B     C     0   (-) 0   (-) 0   (-)     0
#> 4 B     D     0  (0%) 2 (50%) 2 (50%)     4
```

This replaces the questionable `0/0 = 0%` with simply `-` for a cleaner(IMO) result.